# Creating component (and its content) according to our choice in angular2

Tags: angular

This is just a curious question which arised due to my project architecture.

In my project, some piece of code is repeated whenever I create new component.
The below is just a demo, several lines of code are repeated and I need to copy and paste such codes for uniformity in project.

Is there any way/method available by which we can decide the `content` of `.ts/html` of a component at the time of component creation?

Any Idea or approach or solution is welcomed.

### For E.g:-

### abc.component.ts

```
    title: 'billy';
    width: 500;
    height:600;
    ,
    ,
    ,
    ngOnInit(){
     try {
      this.gridId = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['gridId'];
      this.gridWidth = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['gridWidth'];
      this.gridHeight = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['gridHeight'];
      this.data = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['data'];
      this.gridStatus = true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.info('Not Gridster :: ' + e.status);
    }

    if (this.data) {
      this.buildChart(this.data);
    }
    // For Default Data from json
    else {
      try {
        let self = this;
        this.jsonDataService.getChartDefaultData().subscribe(
          function (success) {
            self.data = success;
            self.buildChart(success);
          },
          error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));
      } catch (e) { console.error('Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(e)); }
    }
    }
  buildChart(jsonData) {
this.title = jsonData['meta']['title'];
    this.chartId = jsonData['meta']['chartId'];
    this.width = jsonData['meta']['width'];
    this.height = jsonData['meta']['height'];
    this.viewbys = jsonData['meta']['viewBys'];
    this.viewIds = jsonData['meta']['viewIds'];
    this.measures = jsonData['meta']['meassures'];
    this.drillDown = jsonData['meta']['drillDown'];
    this.drillAcross = jsonData['meta']['drillAcross'];
    this.theme = jsonData['meta']['theme'];
    let showLegend = jsonData['meta']['displayLegends'];
    let showLabels = jsonData['meta']['displayLabels'];

}
```

### abc.component.html

```
<div class='unifrom'>_
_
_
</div>
```

### bcd.component.ts

```
    title: 'billy';
    width: 500;
    height:600;
    ,
    ,
    ,
    ngOnInit(){
     try {
      this.gridId = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['gridId'];
      this.gridWidth = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['gridWidth'];
      this.gridHeight = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['gridHeight'];
      this.data = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['data'];
      this.gridStatus = true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.info('Not Gridster :: ' + e.status);
    }

    if (this.data) {
      this.buildChart(this.data);
    }
    // For Default Data from json
    else {
      try {
        let self = this;
        this.jsonDataService.getChartDefaultData().subscribe(
          function (success) {
            self.data = success;
            self.buildChart(success);
          },
          error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));
      } catch (e) { console.error('Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(e)); }
    }
    }
  buildChart(jsonData) {
this.title = jsonData['meta']['title'];
    this.chartId = jsonData['meta']['chartId'];
    this.width = jsonData['meta']['width'];
    this.height = jsonData['meta']['height'];
    this.viewbys = jsonData['meta']['viewBys'];
    this.viewIds = jsonData['meta']['viewIds'];
    this.measures = jsonData['meta']['meassures'];
    this.drillDown = jsonData['meta']['drillDown'];
    this.drillAcross = jsonData['meta']['drillAcross'];
    this.theme = jsonData['meta']['theme'];
    let showLegend = jsonData['meta']['displayLegends'];
    let showLabels = jsonData['meta']['displayLabels'];

}
```

### bcd.component.html

```
<div class='unifrom'>_
_
_
</div>
```

### cde.component.ts

```
    title: 'billy';
    width: 500;
    height:600;
    ,
    ,
    ,
    ngOnInit(){
     try {
      this.gridId = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['gridId'];
      this.gridWidth = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['gridWidth'];
      this.gridHeight = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['gridHeight'];
      this.data = this.injector.get('chartData')[0]['data'];
      this.gridStatus = true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.info('Not Gridster :: ' + e.status);
    }

    if (this.data) {
      this.buildChart(this.data);
    }
    // For Default Data from json
    else {
      try {
        let self = this;
        this.jsonDataService.getChartDefaultData().subscribe(
          function (success) {
            self.data = success;
            self.buildChart(success);
          },
          error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));
      } catch (e) { console.error('Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(e)); }
    }
    }
  buildChart(jsonData) {
this.title = jsonData['meta']['title'];
    this.chartId = jsonData['meta']['chartId'];
    this.width = jsonData['meta']['width'];
    this.height = jsonData['meta']['height'];
    this.viewbys = jsonData['meta']['viewBys'];
    this.viewIds = jsonData['meta']['viewIds'];
    this.measures = jsonData['meta']['meassures'];
    this.drillDown = jsonData['meta']['drillDown'];
    this.drillAcross = jsonData['meta']['drillAcross'];
    this.theme = jsonData['meta']['theme'];
    let showLegend = jsonData['meta']['displayLegends'];
    let showLabels = jsonData['meta']['displayLabels'];

}
```

### cde.component.html

```
<div class='unifrom'>_
_
_
</div>
```

Comment: you can create interfaces

Comment: Please, put some examples, so that we can understand.

Comment: m not good in angular but according to oops ..create a service and  declare all vriable in it and access serivce in all your components...   then just call variable and functions in your service from components

Answer (score 0):

Create a service `brigdeService`

```
export class BridgeService{
   public weight = 0;
   public height = 0;
   public title = '';


}
```

In your components access it by initialize in constructor

```
export class abcComponent{
  constructor(public bridge: BridgeService){}
  ngOnInit(){
     this.bridge.weight /// get or call all same methods
  }

}
```

for eg . create a service to get all notification in all views just create class 
which initialize in all component and call directly in views.

Comment: You can create a "component base" and extends all rest from it. You must use super() in the constructor, and you can override some functions. You can also use <T> if you need resolve some functin that return different type of object

Comment: @Eliseo, can you please give small example.

Comment: example added :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template:'<div></div>'
})
export class BaseComponent<T> implements OnInit  {  //<--optional <T>
   //Your public variables
    variable1:string="Hello";
    ngOnInit(){
      //your code
    }
    commonFunction1(){}
    commonFunction2(data:T){} //<--function require argument typeof T
    commonFunction2():T  //<--function return T
    {
       data:T
       return data;
    }
```

//Other component

```
interface Idata
{
}
export class AbcComponent extends BaseComponent<Idata>  {
@Component({
 templateUrl: './Abc.component.html'})
 export class AbcComponent  {
   constructor()
   {
     super();
   }
   variablel1:string="Good By";
   commonFunction1(){
        //This override the function1 of base
   }
}
```